# Selenium / Nightwatch - Give absolute path to java executable

Tags: java, selenium, nightwatch.js

We have a Java (7) backend, so all machines have Java 7 installed (window, mac). And the backenders don't want it changed to Java 8 by default, cause it could brake some stuff.

For testing we want to switch from selenium v2 to v3. But it requires Java 8.. 
So I wonder if there is a nightwatch / selenium option to set the direct path to the java (8) executable? This way I only have to download the Java executable in to a folder.

I could find a 'stand-alone' option when installing Java, so that nothing gets added to the $PATH.. But nicest thing would be to just have it a /selenium/java/java8 folder

So how would you handle different Java versions normally? And how would you set it up in a case like this?

Comment: You can set any number of JRE versions in Eclipse IDE and while running your project please select Java 8 version/ 7 version respectively.

Comment: Thanks but we are all on IntelliJ IDE's

Comment: I don't know much about IntelliJ but it should have options to set Java Environment while creating a new project. Please check those options and try.